# Flutter get Weekend and Month

Tags: flutter, date, datetime, dart

I need to get the **Date** for the **weekend in Flutter(Only Friday and Saturday)** and the **Date for the first day and the last day of the month**

This is the approach I tried for the weekend **but it doesn´t work**:

```
      var dateuntilfriday = DateTime.now();

      getFriday() async {
        if (dateuntilfriday.weekday == DateTime.friday) {
          dateuntilfriday.add(Duration(days: 0));
          print("1 Executed");
        } else if (dateuntilfriday.weekday == DateTime.saturday) {
          dateuntilfriday.subtract(Duration(days: 1));
          print("2 Executed");
        } else if (dateuntilfriday.weekday == DateTime.sunday) {
          dateuntilfriday.subtract(Duration(days: 2));
          print("3 Executed");
        } else if (dateuntilfriday.weekday == DateTime.monday) {
          dateuntilfriday.add(Duration(days: 4));
          print("4 Executed");
        } else if (dateuntilfriday.weekday == DateTime.tuesday) {
          dateuntilfriday.add(Duration(days: 3));
          print("5 Executed");
        } else if (dateuntilfriday.weekday == DateTime.wednesday) {
          dateuntilfriday.add(Duration(days: 2));
          print("6 Executed");
        } else if (dateuntilfriday.weekday == DateTime.thursday) {
          dateuntilfriday.add(Duration(days: 1));
          print("7 Executed");
        } else {
          print(
              "and Error Occurent while getting the date for the next or last friday");
        }

        print(dateuntilfriday);
      }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this achieves what you are looking for:

```
DateTime weekdayOf(DateTime time, int weekday) => time.add(Duration(days: weekday - time.weekday));
DateTime fridayOf(DateTime time) => weekdayOf(time, 5);
DateTime saturdayOf(DateTime time) => weekdayOf(time, 6);
DateTime firstMonthDayOf(DateTime time) => DateTime(time.year, time.month, 1);
DateTime lastMonthDayOf(DateTime time) => DateTime(time.year, time.month + 1, 0);
```

I used a trick for the last day of the month. Day `[0]` of next month is the last day of this month.

[image]

### Full source code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final now = DateTime.now();
    final df = DateFormat.yMMMMEEEEd();
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text('Today is ${df.format(now)}'),
          const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
          Text('Friday is ${df.format(fridayOf(now))}'),
          const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
          Text('Saturday is ${df.format(saturdayOf(now))}'),
          const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
          Text('First day of month is ${df.format(firstMonthDayOf(now))}'),
          const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
          Text('Last day of month is ${df.format(lastMonthDayOf(now))}'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

DateTime weekdayOf(DateTime time, int weekday) => time.add(Duration(days: weekday - time.weekday));
DateTime fridayOf(DateTime time) => weekdayOf(time, 5);
DateTime saturdayOf(DateTime time) => weekdayOf(time, 6);
DateTime firstMonthDayOf(DateTime time) => DateTime(time.year, time.month, 1);
DateTime lastMonthDayOf(DateTime time) => DateTime(time.year, time.month + 1, 0);
```